# How do you adjust a motorcycle clutch?

Tags: motorcycle, clutch

Again 85 Yamaha 750maxim how do you adjust the clutch...

Comment: I feel this question is unclear. What do you mean by adjust?

Comment: @DucatiKiller I agree that the question you linked as duplicate answers this one, though the 15 year model difference could have an impact, either way great reference. @ OP there are plenty of clutch adjustment walk-throughs online. Are you having a specific issue with adjusting your clutch?

Comment: @MooseLucifer  The cases on these two bikes are essentially the same and the clutch works in the same manner.  No pushrod and a worm gear.

Comment: @DucatiKiller in that case I'll cast my close vote, and I already updooted your linked answer. Thanks for the info!